# cross compile: link to library only available on target system

Tags: c++, linker, cross-compiling

Is there a way to link to a shared library that is only available on the target system, but not on the system used to cross compile? I want to cross compile another shared library that is linked to a shared library on a target system.

In my source code directory there is an include directory that contains header files with the function declarations. I compile the source code via

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -Wall -fPIC -I include/ -c mysource1.cpp
arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -Wall -fPIC -I include/ -c mysource2.cpp
```

There are no errors or warnings in this state. The next command

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -shared -fPIC -rdynamic mysource1.o mysource2.o -L /usr/lib/libtargetsys_shlib.so -Wl,-z,defs -o another_shared_lib.so
```

reports the following error:

```
mysource2.o: In function `my_func_2':
mysource2.cpp:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `share_lib_func'
```

shared_lib_func is present in the target system shared library.

Answer (score 1):

In linking after cross-compiling, you don't need the *native* library, you need the library from the target system. Copy it over to your build system.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering if there is a way to do the linking without having the library at all on the development system. But I think this is not the case.